# Crash when I start Blender 2.83 on Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows

I've just installed Blender 64Bits v2.83 (Os W7 Pro-64b) and when I try to launch it, I have a stealth window (kind for DOS command) which opens and closes immediately, and the program doesn't not open :-(!
Can you help me to solve this problem?
thank you in advance,
Best Regards,
G.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me with  on a Win 8.1 laptop, but I was also getting an error message related to a sound setting. Strangely, I made it work by upgrading my graphics card driver to the latest version, so you can try that. If not, try to see if Win 7 is still supported. Hope this helps! Stay safe.